# jdbc sql server sql query incorret username and password in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jdbc

I want to ask somthing about sql query in jdbc sql server, I am trying to do the Login screen with jdbc sql server driver when I used select statement to do the login screen and I found out an issue which it is the select statement can login with anything write on the edit text in android studio, how do I let the sql query know if the username or password don't exist in the database, it can show a message box said `Incorrect username or password`

Code:

```
try {

                        Connection mainconn = connection();
                        if (mainconn != null) {
                            String sqlquery = "Select * from tblLogin where username = '" + edUsername.getText().toString() + "' and password = '" + edPassword.getText().toString() + "'";
                            Statement st = mainconn.createStatement();
                            ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(sqlquery);
                            while (resultSet.next()) {
                                Id=resultSet.getString("Id");
                            }
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
                    }
```

Comment: what do you think the value of `Id` is if a user is not found with the user/passwd? why not use that in your logic?

Comment: so like I can't find the id = incorrect username or password?